# Get display name of the VF page through expression with $Page

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

Is it possible to get the display name of the visualforce page via expression like {!$Page.vfpage.name} or there are other simmilar ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

```
$CurrentPage.Name
```

See [$CurrentPage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_currentpage.htm)

---

**Referencing another page**

The Partner API has the ApexPage sObject that can be used to get the API name and MasterLabel for the Visualforce pages in an Org. I don't think you can directly access this through Apex.

Instead you can get a PageReference for any Visualforce page using the syntax `Page.existingPageName`. Again, this isn't going to give you the name of the Visualforce page.

Comment: I'd like to use not current pages...to build sidebar with links to existing $Page